# List of integers with sum of previous values

Tags: scala

I am trying to created a function to get the list of previous values. I have a non elegant way of doing it in a function below, but it uses a mutable currValue. I am trying to avoid having this var outside of the map.

My function is:

```
def getSummedList(list: List[Int]) = {
    var currValue = 0
    val newList = list.map {v=>
        currValue += v
        currValue
    }
    newList 
}
```

Comment: You should not ask such questions on SO. You should have tried something and tell us where you are stuck. This is not place where you get code written for you.

Comment: so sorry, reformatted my question. I had tried something but the function seemed crappy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `scan`:

```
def getSummedList(list: List[Int]) = list.scan(0) ( _ + _ ).tail
```

Scan is like `fold` except it keeps each intermediate result. We take the `tail` to get rid of the first zero element.